# Channel Control of Smart TV

Tags: upnp, television, dlna

I have been using the following document to access the RenderingControl Service of a samsung smart TV. So far I can get the volume of the master channel and change it. I am using [Cling](http://4thline.org/projects/cling/) to do it.

http://upnp.org/specs/av/UPnP-av-RenderingControl-v2-Service.pdf

But I have a task ahead to change TV channel and I dont see any action in the document that enables me to do this.

Can someone guide me on how to proceed on this?

Moreover I have tested [Smart Remote App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adi.remote.phone&hl=en) on TV and it can successfully changes channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smart Remote App works only for Samsung smart TVs, it uses UPNP for device discovery and Remote LAN protocol developed by Samsung for Controlling channels and vol.

The protocol can be found in source code of SamyGo Remote for android.